# ASP.NET SOAP Client with a WSDL Endpoint - works using SOAPUI client

Tags: asp.net, wcf, authentication, client, soapui

I am trying to create a SOAP client in ASP.NET, framework 3.5, using Basic Authentication and WS Security

EDIT: I have added a WSDL as a service reference now

Endpoint is something like: https://webservice.com/GetFirstName
and the WSDL is: https://webservice.com/wsdl?
I have a username and password.

USING SMARTBEAR SOAP UI client (great tool!), I got this to work by creating an XML request like:
    <'element'>
       '<'UserID'>'frank1<''<'UserID'>
    <'element'>

Then I enter the Endpoint URL, credentials.

When I execute, I hit the endpoint with username/password, authenticates, and I get an XML response like:

```
<'data contentType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8" contentLength="515">
'<!['CDATA[<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?'>'
        <'element'>
          <'FirstName'>Frank<'/FirstName>
        <'/element'>
```

So the above is working in SOAP UI Client.

So now how do I go about transitioning this to work in an ASP.NET application? I have some experience with WCF, but don't know where to start.

How can I create a SOAP object envelope, using Basic authentication, populate the SOAP header with credentials, populate the body with the example XMl above, and then target the URL endpoint to get this to work? (Hope I have worded this correctly)

Comment: What is the benefit of enclosing XML in CDATA?

Comment: @SiKing - Using `<![CDATA[]>` prevents the XML parser from trying to parse the contents wrapped by the CDATA tag, so you can use XML special characters - like `<` and `>` - and still parse the XML.  The contents of CDATA will not be parsed.

Comment: Hi Thanks note that I do need to parse the XML so I should request the web service to have 'CDATA" tag removed correct?

Comment: also I have managed to generate a WSDL, so now I can add a service reference - but I still need to figure out how to form and send the XML request to the service

Comment: If you've generated a service reference, WCF should take care of creating the actual SOAP message, you shouldn't need to do it by hand.

Comment: Thanks - so I have generated a service reference. When I click on that reference, in object browser, I see the following: 1) https://webservice.com/GetFirstNameCompletedEventArgs 2)https://webservice.com/GetFirstNameCompletedEventHandler 3)WebServiceProvider.  4)element      How do I go about using these to create the SOAP message and send to the endpoint?

Comment: Hi I have figured out how to use the 'WebServiceProvider' and the element object, as well as ICredentials, to finally authenticate to the webservice and invoke the method. However, now I am getting a very strange issue: Client found response content type of 'text/xml', but expected 'text/xml'.\r\nThe request failed with an empty response.